# Order By on Computed Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want my sql statement to use order by clause using Case Statement
and the column in used in order by is a computed column, for example:

```
declare @pOrderBy int
set @pOrderBy=1
Select ArtistId as Counting, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  
CASE WHEN (@pOrderBy = 1) THEN "Counting" end)
from master.dbo.Album
```

I got the error

```
Invalid column name 'Counting'.
```

I want to mention here that in actual query my `Counting` column is a computed column like:

```
Count(*) as Counting
```

Comment: Why is this table in the `master` database?

Comment: just for testing purpose

Comment: Probably a good idea to start testing somewhere else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse the column alias at the same level as it is defined.

In this case I would just use `ORDER BY ArtistId` rather than trying to reuse the alias. For more complicated expressions you might consider defining it in a CTE or a `CROSS APPLY` [as discussed in this article](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tip-apply-and-reuse-column-aliases).

Answer (score 2):

a quick write up

```
declare @pOrderBy int
set @pOrderBy=1
Select ArtistId as Counting, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  
CASE WHEN (@pOrderBy = 1) THEN ArtistId end)
from master.dbo.Album
```